# DocumentChangeEvent('change:data) doesn't detect <imageInline> insert when load html from DB

Tags: ckeditor5

Try to log model document changes by:

```js
editor.model.document.on<DocumentChangeEvent>('change:data', () => { const changes = editor.model.document.differ.getChanges(); for (const change of changes) { console.log('model change', change); } });
```

When insert an inline image, it works as expected and export html to save to DB.
But the confuse is when load html from DB to editor, the "imageBlock" could get the type: insert log print in console but "imageInline" does not.
Have gone through the document but didn't find any information.
What I want to do is get some authorization token from back-end server when the "imageBlock/Inline" has been loaded then I can use the response info to change the image source attribute (src) then after that the image would show in editor.

imageInline could be captured by editor document event: 'change:data' when load html from DB.

We're using Angular14 ("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^6.0.1").
And use event listener on editor onReady() event.